# How to access a website using SOCKS proxy in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, web-crawler

I'm attending an online Python course for beginners. The content of a unit is to teach students to extract all links in the source code of a webpage. The code is as follows, with `Block_of_Code` unknown:

```
def get_page(url):
    <Block_of_Code>

def get_next_target(page):
    start_link=page.find('<a href=')
    if start_link==-1:
        return None,0
    start_quote=page.find('"',start_link)
    end_quote=page.find('"',start_quote+1)
    url=page[start_quote+1:end_quote]
    return url,end_quote

def print_all_links(page):
    while True:
        url,endpos=(get_next_target(page))
        if url:
            print(url)
            page=page[endpos:]
        else:
            break

print_all_links(get_page('https://youtube.com'))
```

If I were not in China, the `Block_of_Code` should not have been a problem for me. As far as I know, it may have been:

```
import urllib.request
return urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
```

But here in China, certain websites (youtube included) are blocked. So the above code doesn't apply to them.

**My goal** for `Block_of_Code` is to get the source code of any website, whether blocked or not.

I have searched on Google and found some codes using socks proxy, but none of them worked. For example, I wrote and tried the following code based on [this article](https://doomzhou.github.io/coder/2015/03/09/Python-Requests-socks-proxy.html) (having executed `pip install PySocks`).

```
import socket
import socks
import urllib.request

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 2012)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
return urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
```

The error message is:

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

The reason for my searching for code using socks proxy is that I have always been using socks proxy service to visit blocked websites. By launching an app provided by my service provider, I am able to visit those websites using a web browser like Firefox. (My socks proxy port is 2012)

Nevertheless, any kind of solution is welcome, whether it is socks proxy or not, as long as it will enable me to get the source of any page.

I'm using Python 3.6.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: Both methods described in the article you linked work fine on my system (win 7, python 2.7 and python 3.6). What response do you get from your code?

Comment: @t.m.adam Sorry for my late reply. I have just added the error message in my question. By the way, for me, both methods work too, but only for websites not blocked in our country by [the Great Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall). For blocked websites, the second method is supposed to work, as it works for some of my compatriots. But somehow it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with your code, in fact i run it (using tor as socks5 proxy) and got 241 links. Have you tried with another proxy? You can get some free http/s proxies here [https://free-proxy-list.net/](https://free-proxy-list.net/)

Comment: @t.m.adam I tried a free proxy in your link. Still failed. `ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`